# Uploading image with editable div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello I am trying to upload data to the database suing ajax call I have created a script but the problem is that I had a textarea but for some reasons i CHANGED that textarea to and editable div now my question is how do i get data from that div

```
 <form method="POST" action="" id="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false;">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-photo"></i> Upload A Photo / Document
                        <input type="file" name="image" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id='display'></div>
                <div id="contentbox" contenteditable="true" name="post_dt">
                </div>

                <input type="submit" id="sb_art" class="btn_v2" value="Start Discussion" />
            </form>
```

And this is my ajax script created for uploading data

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("#post").on('submit', (function(e) {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
        $("#load").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#load").css("display", "none");
    });

    var form = this;
    var content = $("#contentbox").html();
    $.ajax({
        url         : "url/demo/forums/post_forum",
        type        : "POST",
        data        : {new FormData(this), content: content},
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false,
        success     : function(data) {
            $("#data_update").prepend($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
            form.reset();
        }
    });
}));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the correct method to get the content from the editable element: `html()`. Your issue is how you're sending the data. When sending binary data through `FormData` you cannot place that inside an object to be encoded. Instead, the additional data must be added to the `FormData` using `append()`. Try this:

```
$("#post").on('submit', function(e) {
  $("#load").show();
  var form = this;
  var formData = new FormData(this);
  formData.append('content', $("#contentbox").html());

  $.ajax({
    url: "http://tfsquare.com/demo/forums/post_forum",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $("#data_update").prepend($(data).fadeIn('slow'));
      form.reset();
      $("#contentbox").empty();
    },
    complete: function() {
      $("#load").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that I changed your use of `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxComplete()` to use the `complete` method. Defining new global AJAX handlers on every submit of the form is rather redundant.

Comment: Thank you it worked great for me but after posting the content div is not resetting

Comment: It's not a form element, so `form.reset()` won't work on it. Use `$("#contentbox").empty()`. I updated the answer for you

Comment: but by adding your query got another error wich i forgot to tell you the image is not coming up though

Comment: no error coming up the image file is empty like no image nname coming neither image and also loader is not working as well though let me debug in console see if image name pop ups

Comment: The image file is empty

Comment: It may be worth starting a new question about it, including the server side code you're using to receive the data